# Is there a ranked order for the Phantom 4?

Tags: fairy-tail

Previously the Element 4 was a group of four S-Class Mages who were the most strongest in the Phantom Lord Guild. However was there ever a ranking/official ranking in terms of who was stronger?

The only information I can gather is the Aria was the strongest out of the Element 4. Was there any information that gave insight into the ranking on strength? It may have been already revealed in the anime, however I have forgotten if it was mentioned.

Answers are appreciated. :)

Comment: don't remember reading anything on this in the manga.. nor does the Fairy Tail wiki have anything on it.

Comment: I don't think there's a ranked order for them, but looking for their fight against FT, the order from strongest to weakest will likely be Aria-Juvia-Totomaru-Sol

Answer (score 1):

On Aria's Fairy Tail Wikipedia page it states that "he is considered the strongest member of the group".

This by no means concrete evidence that he is indeed the strongest, but he did manage to sneak upon Makarov and disable him for a short time. So as for official order there really is none, they were all S-Class mages so in terms of strength they were at least on the same playing field. So an example "ranking" could be:

1. Aria
2. Juvia
3. Sol
4. Totomaru

This is by no means the correct way to rank them and it really depends on your personal opinion.